# Python Web/UI Options

Tags: python, user-interface

We are in the process of standing up a UI on top of a python system.  This is all throw away code, so we want something quick, yet presentable.

We will have a couple of "interfaces" but they will be of two types.  One will be control, it will basically be sitting on top of a python thread, and accepting requests from the user.

The other will be more of a display screen that will need to be able to display images, and some classic "grid views" of text to the user.

We pretty much know we could* do all of this in HTML but wasn't sure what would be the best way to interact with the core python code?

Anyone know of a good UI python presentation layer?  Since we know we can do all of this in HTML/Jquery pretty quickly, we are also open to suggestions on how to integrate this with a web server..

Any suggestions?  Really interested in finding out if there is any way to use python as the back end to a webserver.

Let me know if you all need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have found the [DJango](http://www.djangoproject.com/) meets our needs.  It is a pretty slick mvc style python web stack.  Really is easy to use, and very quick to develop in.  I will say that the ORM layer is a little young so it is hard to do some simple queries, but luckly since this is throw away code we can just use native sql.

Answer (score 3):

I like [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/). The demo application is excellent and lets you browse, tweak and re-run the code right in the demo.

Comment: wxPython is awful to code in ;)  we were hoping to use something a little more "smart" or higher level..

Comment: Well, I guess it's a matter of taste. I feel the same about HTML+jQuery ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is probably going to be the solution you can use quickest. Its API is simple and straight-forward, and you probably already have it installed.

Answer (score 0):

As the other 2 classic Python GUI options have been given already, I feel duty bound to suggest PyQt :)

Using QT Designer I've found it much simpler than TKInter to get some basic GUIs up and running. Build your GUI up in a WYSIWYG way, then hook it up to the back-end logic. I've also found that the large amount of C++ help on QT available on the interent usually translates more or less directly across to PyQt. The resources available for TKInter are IMO pretty obtuse, and simply stop as soon as you want to do anything more interesting than Hello World. YMMV.

The [Rapid GUI Programming with Python and QT](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html) book is a fantastic resource. Had me programming real applications in no time.